# I am bugged out on the Krakauer quest, please help

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am on the following two quests in Eastern Kingdoms / Redridge Mountains as a Level 18 Warrior:

- Krakauer (Kill Ritualist Tarak)
- His Heart Must Be In It (Keeshan's Red Headband and Jade Amulet)

I am currently stuck, because while trying to complete the Krakauer quest, I got killed by Ritualist Tarak. Now the entirety of Redridge Mountains is bugged. I can't complete the two quests above, because there are two boulders blocking the road to the cave where Ritualist Tarak resides. Messner and Jorgensen keep following me, while in Redridge Mountains, waiting for me to complete the quest. I am not offered any other quests until I complete the above two, so I am basically at a stand still.

In trying to complete the above quests, despite the bug, I have managed to jump my way around the obstacle (the two boulder blocking the way). Still, there is no cave allowing me to get to Ritualist Tarak to complete "Krakauer" or "His Heart Must Be In It."

I am not sure what to do at this point, since I cannot progress further in the game without completing these quests.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the best approach right now is to get help from an ingame gamemaster (gm). Have you tried that?

Comment: Just drop the quest and pick it up again.

Comment: Do what @Virusboy sais, drop the quests and restart them.

Comment: Hi @Michael did you ever sort this out? If so, do you want to share what you did as an answer?